Error conexión a mi servidor web IIS desde iphone con datos móviles
tenemos un servidor IIS dado de alta al que apuntan estos dos dominios: https://app.aparejadoresalbacete.es https://icolegia.aparejadoresalbacete.es  Ambos en el mismo sitio web.
Podemos acceder a nuestro sitio web, desde móviles Android, Pc's , ordenadores Mac, desde Wifi o Datos.
Sin embargo, cuando entramos con un móvil iPhone a estos dominios desde una WIFI, todo correcto, pero si entramos con Datos Móviles con un iPhone a la web https://icolegia.aparejadoresalbacete.es no nos contesta aparece un error, lo escribo más abajo.
Pero a la web  https://app.aparejadoresalbacete.es  si que contesto.
Y lo más raro, si con iPhone entramos  a la web https://icolegia.aparejadoresalbacete.es  desde una VPN extranjera, también conseguimos conectar con nuestra página.
¿Alguna ayuda?
ERROR: fetch event respondwith received an error: typeError: load failed  Fetch API cannot load: "url servicio web"  Failed to load resource: FetchEvent.respondWith received an error: TypeError: Load failed
